# Undefined control sequence inside equation math mode

Tags: equations

heyy:)

I try to write an equation using \alpha , \beta, \delat and \gamma inside the `equation` of LaTex. And I use `split` such that i have multiple lines inside the equation without numbering all the lines individually

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    f'(x',y') &= [a\alpha^2 + b\alpha\gamma]\: x'^2 \\
    &+ [b(\alha\delta + \beta\gamma)+ 2(a\alpha\beta - c\gamma\delta]\:x'y' \\
    &+ [a\beta^2 + b\beta\delta + c\delta^2]\:y'^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

The output should be like this:

```
f′(x′,y′) = [aα2 + bαγ] x′2
          + [b(δ + βγ) + 2(aαβ − cγδ] x′y′                      (1)
          + [aβ2 + bβδ + cδ2] y′2
```

But i get the error undefined control sequence. Does someone know how I need to write this equation such that it works?
These are my packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: well really look at the error message. It tells you which command is undefined. And then correct alha to alpha.

Comment: If you don't see which control sequence is undefined in the error message then something is wrong. Maybe your user interface which you are running TeX doesn't print it. Then I recommend: replace such a user interface by better one.

Comment: some editors hide the error message (texstudio is spectacularly bad with undefined command errors) always check the log file.  Also only use `split` if you need its complexity, I would use `aligned` here and in almost all cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot:) Im not very used to read error messages in LaTex therefore I just missed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelt `\alpha`

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    f'(x',y') &= [a\alpha^2 + b\alpha\gamma]\: x'^2 \\
    &+ [b(\alpha\delta + \beta\gamma)+ 2(a\alpha\beta - c\gamma\delta]\:x'y' \\
    &+ [a\beta^2 + b\beta\delta + c\delta^2]\:y'^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot:) I just didn't see that and tried some crazy stuff instead :')

Answer (score 2):

You did not show the error message.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    f'(x',y') &= [a\alpha^2 + b\alpha\gamma]\: x'^2 \\
    &+ [b(\alha\delta + \beta\gamma)+ 2(a\alpha\beta - c\gamma\delta]\:x'y' \\
    &+ [a\beta^2 + b\beta\delta + c\delta^2]\:y'^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Produces the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...lpha \gamma ]\: x'^2 \\ &+ [b(\alha 
                                                  \delta + \beta \gamma )+ 2...
l.9 \end{split}
               
?
```

This higlights the undefined command `\alha` by the linebreak.

Comment: Just a hint for the OP. this looks beter if you in the first line replace `&=` by `= {} &`, then the starting `+` on the other lines are quitable indented and not listed under the `=` (which IMO they should not)